# Using STDIN in Symfony Process

Tags: symfony, process

I'm trying to send some data through STDIO in a Symfony Process.

```
$process = new Process([
    'php',
    'bin/console',
    'whatever:command'
]);
```

Once the process is running, I want to send something through STDIO (Input !== STDIO), but seems that is not possible.

BTW, Process uses the PHP function `proc_open`, where the third parameter is an array, having as the position 0 a file pointer for the STDIO. The problem is that this array is not accessible.

Did anyone find a solution for that?
How can I send something through STDIO without changing the Process class?

Answer (score 2):

The `Process` class takes a 4th argument to it's constructor, you could pass in `STDIO` there.